# Java does not serialize my object correctly

Tags: java, serialization

I have a problem with this code :

```
public class DataController {

    DataController() {}

    Wallet getWallet(String name){

        ObjectInputStream ois;
        File file = new File(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getDefaultDirectory(), "wallets/" + name);
        Wallet wallet;

        try {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            wallet = (Wallet) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            return wallet;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    void save(Wallet wallet){

        ObjectOutputStream oos;
        File file = new File(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getDefaultDirectory(), "wallets/wallet" + wallet.getName() + ".txt");

        try {
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

            if (!file.exists()) {
                oos.writeObject(wallet);
            }
            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    String[] listWallets(){

        File file = new File(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getDefaultDirectory(), "wallets");

        if (file.exists() && file.list().length > 0) {
            return file.list();
        } else {
            return new String[]{"No wallets"};
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the save method, it's supposed to serialize my Wallet object in a file but, it writes weird chars (Ԁ). I don't expect what goes wrong. Does anyone view what is the error ?

My Wallet Class :

```
package fr.paragoumba.mywallet;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Wallet implements Serializable {

    Wallet(String name) {
        this.name =  name;
    }


    public String toString(){
        return "Nom : " + name + "\nFonds : " + founds;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume `Wallet` is not `Serializable` even though it should implement Serializable

Comment: to prove serialization is working you need to read the serialized object back and check its valid and equal to the original object you serialized.

Comment: What do those "weird" chars represent? Some data? If so, what's the original data and what's your system's default encoding? And most importantly: how do you read that file, i.e. where did you see those "weird" chars?

Comment: Please include your `Wallet` class in its entirety in your question

Comment: The serializaton is not in plain text. Read the file with a Stream to get the instance back. Every not transient variable should be there.

Comment: What would you expect in the files? _Weird chars_ (as in binary data) seems pretty reasonable for me as serialized objects.

Comment: 'It writes weird chars' is not the same thing as 'refuses to serialize'. Unclear what you're asking, NB It is impossible for `file.exists()` to be false at the point you are testing it, so you are actually serializing nothing at all.

Comment: make sure that `Wallet`  class is implementing `Serializable`

Comment: Why file.exists() can't be false ?

Comment: I don't know what I expect exactly in my file but when I try to read my object, it returns an EOFException.

Comment: It can't be false because you just created it with `new FileOutputStream(...)`, and if that had failed there would have been an `IOException`. And writing to a file that doesn't exist doesn't make any sense in the first place.

Comment: The `EOFException` is because you didn't serialize anything, exactly as I said.

Comment: When I write to the file there is no exception, it creates it. I think that the cause of the problem isn't in the reading process but in the writing process. I've tested with another object and it works (with many datas in the file) but here I don't get what I expect. Writing to a file that doesn't exists to create it have works with the other object so I've just replaced it.

Comment: That is exactly what I have been telling you. There *is* no writing process, because you have self-contradictory logic which prevents it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't serializing anything except an `ObjectOutputStream` header.

```
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
```

That creates `file`, or throws an `IOException`.

```
if (!file.exists())
```

So this can never be false.

```
oos.writeObject(wallet);
```

so this can never execute. Very strange code. Why would you try to write to a file that doesn't exist?

```
oos.close();
```

As you aren't writing anything else to the file, if you try to read an object from it you will get an `EOFException`.

Comment: The `Wallet` argument in save() is filled with its name and its funds (at 0) so the object isn't void.

Comment: Ok, if I delete the if(!file.exists) it works (as you said) but if I don't want to replace my file by what can I replace this if ?

Comment: You need to *remove* the `exists()` test. It is absolutely pointless.